# Change running tween speed

Tags: phaser

I have words inside a tween and I need to slow down a tween that is already running and I am using updateTweenData to do so. All running tweens are in an array.

updateTweenData works, but the problem is, when I set the slower speed, words become closer together and when I set the normal speed, words space out.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0txgwko/) that demonstrates the problem.
Just click slower/faster buttons and notice how words behave.

I want just the speed to change and everything else to remain the same.
How can I achieve this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objects cover the same distance (400px) in 40 or in 80 seconds, it's going to have an impact on the spacing if the objects start with a fixed delay of 2 seconds (values taken from your jsfiddle).

First of all, you should incorporate the delay into the tween itself (use the `delay` property). Then, instead of using different durations for the tweens, use the [`timeScale`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Tween.html#timeScale) property to speed-up or slow-down your tweens.

As an additional measure you'll probably also want to ensure that your tweens use linear easing.

**Update:** Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68mLkL6n/) that incorporates what I outlined in my answer.